# How to test a dispatch function?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hello I'm trying to test this function with the return of the `dispatch` in how many times it have been called, but really don't know how to do it correctly in order to call `dispatch`

```js
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        hideSidebar: () => {
            dispatch(hideSidebar)
        },
        updateUnit: (unitObject) => {
            dispatch(settingsActions.updateArray(unitObject))
        }
    }
}
```

I have these test

```js
describe('mapDispatchToProps', () => {
    test('test', () => {
        const dispatch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
        mapDispatchToProps(dispatch)
        expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
    })
})
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: btw dispatch will be called 0 times after calling mapDispatchToProps

Comment: @PavelKratochvil yeah, but how can I called?

Comment: mapDispatchToProps is function which returns object so store the object in variable, and call hideSidebar or updateUnit on that object. Then you can expect how many times was it called. But i am not sure about testing like this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `dispatch` mock function and pass it to `mapDispatchToProps`.

Then call the functions defined on the result.

You can use something like [`toHaveBeenCalledWith`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-) to verify that the correct action was dispatched:

```
// Stubs for hideSidebar and settingsActions.updateArray
const hideSidebar = { type: 'hide-side-bar' };
const settingsActions = { updateArray: u => ({ type: 'update-unit', payload: u })};

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    hideSidebar: () => {
      dispatch(hideSidebar)
    },
    updateUnit: (unitObject) => {
      dispatch(settingsActions.updateArray(unitObject))
    }
  }
}

test('mapDispatchToProps', () => {
  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  const map = mapDispatchToProps(dispatch);

  map.hideSidebar();
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: 'hide-side-bar' });  // Success!

  map.updateUnit({ theKey: 'theVal' });
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: 'update-unit', payload: { theKey: 'theVal' } });  // Success!
})
```